# Recovery data from LVM rewritten partition tables

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, data-recovery, disk

During installation on my USB unfittingly I start installation on my own disk and the partition tables of LVM are replaced.

I have 3 partitions and they are replced identically.
I can mount boot partition and get data with UUID from `grub.cfg` but I don't have a backup of LVM from etc

I tried `vgcreate --UUID` from grub but doesn't work. Also, tried testdisk but doesn't work.

Can someone explain me is there any way to recover creating with the same UUID from group with `vgcreate` from begging or some kind of mount data to recovery?

Comment: Has your system been running since this has happened or have you rebooted it / shut it down?

Comment: The system is turned off. No access to system after partition table has been changed

Answer (score 0):

Consider LVM like another way to partition, but not with classic MBR.

give results of those commands :

> sudo vgdisplay ; sudo pvdisplay ; sudo lvdisplay

if you're lucky this is all here you will just have to activate all of partitions (PV) rebuild VG & LV & mount them again.

Comment: Yes, I can active the current (last) created. But, they don't have ext4 filesystem and its request to format. Because when I try to mount the error is the wrong FS.

Comment: I think then, you just can't retrieve your datas